# Why is my index.html not taking my style.css in my css folder?

Tags: html, css, xampp

I have this following file structure:

```
mysite/
├── css/
│   ├── style.css
│   
├── index.html
```

And my html code is:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
    <title>Home </title>
</head>
```

But when I run the site on the localhost (xampp), it is not taking the CSS.
For as long as I know, I have been doing this all the time but its not working this time.

FYI: My Apache in xampp is indeed running.

Can anyone spot my mistake?

Comment: try putting href="../css/style.css" since you need to go back one directory level

Comment: Check my answer, If it helped u the please accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css" type="text/css">
```

I am assuming that you have a **css folder** and **index.html** file in your **mysite folder**.

In order to get the css file, you wil have to use above format, which tells **index.html** file to go to **css folder** and get **style.css** file

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 0):

try to put ../css/style.css to go back, your html file isn't in the same directory with the css one.

Answer (score 0):

Check the network tab inside the developer console and see if it indeed loads. Also, try doing

```
style.css?random=number
```

Dev console: F12 in FF, CTRL+SHIFT+I on chrome.